# Array of Char or Storing a string in a struct without a pointer (Not using NSString - I think) in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-structures, string, nsstring

I'm creating a game in objective C using the cocos 2d engine for iPhone. Currently i'm sending packets of data to and from clients using structs:

```
typedef struct
{
PacketType type;
CGPoint position;
int amount;
int playerId;
} PacketPlayerDamage;
```

My problem is I want to send a string in the same format, otherwise I have to make some pretty major changes, ideally the following would work:

```
typedef struct
{
    PacketType type;
    NSString *name;
} PacketHello
```

I believe this doesn't work as when i'm wrapping up my packet to send it I do the following:

```
PacketPlayerDamage packet;
packet.type = kPacketTypePlayerDamage;
packet.amount = amount;
packet.playerId = playerId;
NSData* sendPacket = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:sizeof(packet)];
[self sendToAll:sendPacket];
```

Which fails to unwrap a NSString and throws an error, possibly because it doesn't know the size/length of that variable in the struct.

So since, I don't really want to modify the way I wrap or unwrap my data packet (i was converting NSMutableDictionary's to JSON and everything was fine, but that seems like a step backwards) but I want to allow the sending of a string (obviously fixed string length/size is fine, i.e. 32 characters), my question is....

Is there an easy way to handle a fixed length string without a pointer in objective C, array of 32 chars or something similar?

I've seen the following:

```
UTF8String option1;
Str32 option2;
```

Are they what i'm looking for? If so, how do I take a max 32 char NSString and apply it to them (, and I guess the title isn't as relevant...)

Thanks for you help,

JT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **- (BOOL)getCString:(char *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)maxBufferCount encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding** method on NSString. So you would add add a char array to your struct  with a fixed length and use the method above to write the NSString into it:

```
typedef struct
{
    PacketType type;
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
} PacketHello

NSString* toSend = @"blahblahblah";
PacketHello myPacket;
[toSend getCString:myPacket.name maxLength:MAX_LENGTH encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

On the recieving end you can convert it back to an NSString with **- (id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding**

```
PacketHello received;
NSString* name = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:received.name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Just a note: MAX_LENGTH *includes* space for a null byte, so if you want to send 32 characters it should be 33.

Comment: Worked a charm... Cheers Drew.